# Pointer to string management in C: Replacing specific characters in a string

Tags: c, string, string.h

I want to replace all cases of ",," in a line from a .csv file with ",-1,". Prior to this id also like to add a comma to the end of the line.

I've tried to get it by splitting the line in to two sub strings one of the stuff before the ,, and one after, then concatenating them, but I've probably mess up with the stuff each thing is pointing too.

Also Prior too this operation I'd like to add a additional comma at the end of the file so if there is a missing value at the end as well that gets taken care off.

```
//Get line from file
char line[70];
fgets(line, 70, infile);

//Add "," to the end of the line
char * temp;
temp = strstr(line, "/n");
strncpy(temp, ",/n", 2);
puts(line);

//Process Line
while (strstr(line, ",,") != NULL) {
    char * temp; 
    char endTemp[50];
    temp = strstr(line, ",,");
    strcpy(endTemp, temp + 2);
    strncpy(temp, ",-1,", 4);
    strcat(temp, endTemp);
    puts(line);
}
```

I think I've messed up with the two sub strings I pull out of line, since if the starting string is something like:

ajd43,232,,0,0,0,3

it prints

ajd43,232,-1,0,0,0,3
,(/n)0,0,0,3

I think the error is in the strcat at the end but if their is an easier way to do this operation I'd like to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Your "/n"s should be "\n"s.

(2) Use strncpy(temp, ",\n", 3); or manually add a null char at temp[2] after.

(3) Use strncpy(temp, ",-1,", 5); or manually add a null char at temp[4] after.

(4) Consider truncating and using strcat over strncpy.

(5) Check for overruns if this is to be used in production.

(6) Just replace the newline with a comma.  puts() will add it back. (thus changing #2)

like this:

```
// Get line from file
char line[70];
fgets(line, 70, infile);

//Add "," to the end of the line
char * temp;
temp = strstr(line, "\n");
strcpy(temp, ",");

//Process Line
while (strstr(line, ",,") != NULL) {
    char * temp; 
    char endTemp[70];
    temp = strstr(line, ",,");
    strcpy(endTemp, temp + 2);
    temp[0] = '\0';
    strncat(line, ",-1,", 70);
    strncat(line, endTemp, 70);
}
puts(line);
```